# Cannot send session cache limiter. Session not working

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I know this is a very common question that has been asked a million times. I've searched through the Web but none of the solutions worked for me; ive checked for the notorious extra space...but I still get the message :

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent ......

I have the following snippet on top of my page:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
$DB_NAME = 'dbnamexyz'; 
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'userxyz'; 
$DB_PASS = 'pass123';  
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Database connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
?>
```

Session is not working, even if I remove the top ob_start()....don't know why.

Comment: So you've checked the encoding of your page to make sure it isn't UTF-8 with BOM?

Comment: How does one do that, then remove the BOM

Comment: What are you using to create/edit your PHP files? Most fine text editors will have a section for modifying encoding.  I use EditPad Lite.

Comment: It is Dreamweaver

Comment: Go to `Edit->Preferences->New Document` and see if the checkbox `Include Unicode Signature (BOM)` is checked.  If it's checked, uncheck it, trash your php file and create a new one.

Comment: Even without a BOM, a single character of whitespace can cause this problem.

Comment: @RayPaseur well I would hope OP would have checked for that first ;)

Comment: 'Include Unicode Signature' not checked.

Comment: Is this on a server where we can access the URL?  Also,l what is the line number in the error message?

Comment: Line 3.  I'm testing on local pc

Comment: Probably an issue with your dev environment then.  You on win,mac,wamp,xampp?

Comment: It's Windows  xampp

Comment: Try this... start over with a new file, removing Everything except the first three lines - nothing else, no close-php tag, just the three lines.  See if that works (silently) or throws a message.

Comment: @ Ray Paseur, that works. If the page template below is removed or replaced,no error message and session works, don't know why the bottom affects the top